# enable ssl connection filezilla throught powershell v3.0

Tags: windows, ssl, ftp, iis-7.5, powershell-3.0

By using power shell script, I am able to connect my ftp server via normal session. but not able to connect via secure session.
    Whenever i try to connect via ssl its shows error "Requires SSL ". Can any one tell me the parameter to used for power shell.
    Ftp server : IIS

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `System.Net.FtpWebRequest`, set the `EnableSsl` property to true:

```
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://ftp.example.com")
$ftp.EnableSsl = $true
```